# Converting getRandomValue.browser from cuid to Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, encryption, cryptography

[The cuid() library has this function](https://github.com/ericelliott/cuid/blob/master/lib/getRandomValue.browser.js):

```
var getRandomValue;

var crypto = typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
  (window.crypto || window.msCrypto) ||
  typeof self !== 'undefined' &&
  self.crypto;

if (crypto) {
    var lim = Math.pow(2, 32) - 1;
    getRandomValue = function () {
        return Math.abs(crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / lim);
    };
} else {
    getRandomValue = Math.random;
}

module.exports = getRandomValue;
```

I think this is the correct Typescript translation.  I've converted the export slightly, and `window.msCrypto` goes to `window['msCrypto']`

So the result is:

```
var getRandomValueFunction;

var crypto:Crypto = typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
  (window.crypto || window['msCrypto']) ||
  typeof self !== 'undefined' &&
  self.crypto;

if (crypto) {
    var lim = Math.pow(2, 32) - 1;
    getRandomValueFunction = function () {
        return Math.abs(crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / lim);
    };
} else {
    getRandomValueFunction = Math.random;
}

export const getRandomValue = getRandomValueFunction
```

Just want to make sure I did not make any mistakes.  I'm creating a Typescript version of the library.

Also the first answer brought up the question of whether it should be `% lim`?

I'm not an expert in the domain, so any feedback on this as well as how to remove the bias towards low values would be welcome.

Also I think, as suggested, that we can remove the `Math.abs` call since `lim` can never be negative correct?

### The Completed Translation

Once complete the translation will live here, in case any one has additional improvements or suggestions:

https://github.com/fireflysemantics/cuid

I'm packaging it using the Angular Package Format such that it gets support for all the popular module formats.

Comment: This should be question in codereview.stackexchange.com. this looks like it works. You can make sure you use `let` `const` and also arrow functions. Also add the type for the `getRandomValueFunction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks correct translation to me. However, shouldn't it be `% lim` instead of `/ lim`? And even then: the result is somewhat biased towards low values if `lim` is not a power of two.

Besides that, I presume that `lim` is not negative, so I don't see any reason for the call to `abs` function. A single 32 bit unsigned integer should not suddenly turn negative after all, not if it is treated as 64 bit double anyway.

Comment: I think you are right - It should be `% lim` - I created an issue for it here (If we don't do `% lim` the result can contain dashes: https://github.com/ericelliott/cuid/issues/200

Comment: Related SO Issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60676476/eliminating-dashes-from-node-crypto-generated-random-values