# Can crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / lim ever be negative?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cryptography, cryptojs

Curious whether the expression `crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / lim` can ever be negative.

The code I'm converting puts a `Math.abs` wrapper around it, but some of us think that it's impossible for it to be negative, so just wanted to see what the rest of you think?

```
var lim = Math.pow(2, 32) - 1;
crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / lim);
```

This is the related question for more context:
[Converting getRandomValue.browser from cuid to Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668998/converting-getrandomvalue-browser-from-cuid-to-typescript)

The library has a `getRandomValue()` nodejs function that looks like this:

```
import * as crypto from "crypto"

var lim = Math.pow(2, 32) - 1;

export function getRandomValue () {
  return Math.abs(crypto.randomBytes(4)
    .readInt32BE(0) / lim)
}
```

I think for the browser, the `Math.abs` call was kept even though it seems it is not necessary, and quite possibly incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the use of `Math.abs()` would be *wrong!*

The value in question, so says the declaration above, is `UInt32` ... unsigned 32-bit integer.

This simply means that the leftmost bit (most significant bit) *is not* to be interpreted as a sign-bit.  This does not, however, prevent you from inadvertently using the value in some context which *would* assume that `MSB=1` means "negative."

Nonetheless, it would be *wrong* for you to use `abs()` because this would convert the entire bit-pattern, if it finds that `MSB=1`, into an entirely different bit-pattern.  Since the MSB is simply "one of the 32 bits which comprises the value," it is dead-wrong to do anything to it which assumes that it's a sign-bit.  And you also want to take care that it never gets displayed as a negative number, because it isn't.  This quantity is 32 bits long, not 31+sign.  Be sure it always looks that way.

Comment: So based on your answer the code is more correct if we remove `Math.abs()`?    I'm assuming that if it is removed then the code will be correct with respect to the other assertions made in the answer?

Comment: entirely different patter or just mod 2^31